# triangle: distance between segment midpoint and opposite vertex

Tags: geometry, triangles

Assuming I have 3 vertices A, B, C forming a triangle as shown in the picture and the locations (e.g. in 2D) of A and B as well as the distances AC and BC (and obviously AB) are known (but not the location of C). Is there an elegant way of calculating the distance MC where M is the segment midpoint between A and B?
My ugly solution would be to first find the position of C and then simply calculate the distance between C and M. However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way given AB, AC and BC.

[image: triangle]

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Median_of_a_triangle

Comment: Using Heron's formula you can develop a quadratic equation in $MC^2$.

Comment: @Aretino could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?